# How can I plot a graph like this one in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot a graph like the one in the following picture:
[image: two muppets]

I wrote the following code that plots a wave graph for each time step.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def u_0(x):
    a = 1.0/np.cosh(2.0*(x+8.0))
    b = 1.0/np.cosh((x+1.0))
    return 8.0*a*a+2.0*b*b

#spatial grid
N = 100
x = np.linspace(-10,10,N)

#time
Nt = 100
tlist = np.linspace(0.0,2.0,Nt)

#velocity
c = 5.0
count = 0
for t in tlist:
  u = u_0(x-c*t)
  plt.figure()
  plt.plot(x,u)
  plt.savefig(str(count))
  count = count+1
  plt.close()
```

How can I join these pictures together and get a graph like the one in the picture?
Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: you have to plot all on one picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't close plot and draw all on one image.

Every plot would need some offset for Y values

```
u += count  # offset
```

Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def u_0(x):
    a = 1.0/np.cosh(2.0*(x+8.0))
    b = 1.0/np.cosh((x+1.0))
    return 8.0*a*a + 2.0*b*b

# spatial grid
N = 100
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, N)

# time
Nt = 100
tlist = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0, Nt)

#velocity
c = 5.0
count = 0

for t in tlist:
  u = u_0(x-c*t)
  u += count  # offset 
  plt.plot(x, u)
  count += 1

plt.savefig("result.png")
```

Image:

[image]

---

**EDIT:** Something similar in 3D

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D # need for `projection=`
import numpy as np

def u_0(x):
    a = 1.0/np.cosh(2.0*(x+8.0))
    b = 1.0/np.cosh((x+1.0))
    return 8.0*a*a + 2.0*b*b

#velocity
c = 5.0

#spatial grid
N = 30
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, N)
t = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0, N)

X, T = np.meshgrid(x, t)
Y = u_0(X-c*T)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_wireframe(X, T, Y)

plt.show()
plt.savefig('result.png')
```